# Responding to serial input

Tags: c, serial-port, raspberry-pi

This code for the Raspberry Pi board waits for serial input then plays an arrow with a sound and message. I'd like any constructive comments or suggestions.

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <bits/siginfo.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <queue>       


#define BAUDRATE B9600
#define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyUSB0"
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1 /* POSIX compliant source */
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1



volatile int STOP=FALSE; 

void signal_handler_IO (int status);   /* definition of signal handler */
int wait_flag=TRUE;                    /* TRUE while no signal received */

int fd,c, res;
struct termios oldtio,newtio;
struct sigaction saio;           /* definition of signal action */
char buf[255];

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#define w 400 //width
#define l 400 //length
#define mp 3 //multiplier - size of arrow
#define ts 4 //time scale - time to show arrow

//message
void Arrow( Mat img, int i );
int CreateMessage( String tln, int i ); // (Teller number, Arrow 1 left 2   right 3 down) 

//images       
int showImages(int a);
void loadImages(); 
int nImages = 8;
IplImage *images[0];

typedef queue<char*> CHARQUEUE;

//initilaize serial port        
void iSerial(){
fd = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
if (fd <0) {perror(MODEMDEVICE); exit(-1); }

saio.sa_handler = signal_handler_IO;
saio.sa_flags=0;
saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
sigaction(SIGIO,&saio,NULL);

fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FASYNC);

tcgetattr(fd,&oldtio); /* save current port settings */
newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
newtio.c_oflag = 0;
newtio.c_lflag = ICANON;
newtio.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
newtio.c_cc[VTIME]=0;
tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);

tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&oldtio);
  } 

int main()
      {
   CHARQUEUE q;
   loadImages();  
   iSerial();
   while(1){
      for (int i = 0; i < nImages; ++i){ 
             showImages(i);

      /* after receiving SIGIO, wait_flag = FALSE, input is available
         and can be read */
      if (wait_flag==FALSE) { 
        res = read(fd,buf,255);
        buf[res]=0;
        q.push(buf);
        printf(":%s:%d\n", buf, res);
        if (res==1) STOP=TRUE; /* stop loop if only a CR was input */
        wait_flag = TRUE;      /* wait for new input */
     }
        while (!q.empty())
        {
         CreateMessage( q.front(), 2 );
         q.pop();
        }
    }
   }
}


  void signal_handler_IO (int status)
  {
    printf("received SIGIO signal.\n");
    wait_flag = FALSE;
  }

void loadImages() {

images[0] = cvLoadImage("images/001.jpg");
images[1] = cvLoadImage("images/002.jpg");
images[2] = cvLoadImage("images/003.jpg");
images[3] = cvLoadImage("images/004.jpg");
images[4] = cvLoadImage("images/005.jpg");
images[5] = cvLoadImage("images/006.jpg");
images[6] = cvLoadImage("images/007.jpg");
images[7] = cvLoadImage("images/008.jpg");
images[8] = cvLoadImage("images/009.jpg");

}

int showImages(int a){
    cvNamedWindow("pic");
    cvShowImage("pic",images[a]);
    cvMoveWindow("pic", 0, 0);
    cvWaitKey(2000);
}



int CreateMessage( String tln, int i )
 {
 Mat arrow_image = Mat::zeros( w, l, CV_8UC3 );
 putText(arrow_image, "Teller "+tln, cvPoint(100,30), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1.8, cvScalar(200,200,250), 1, CV_AA);
Arrow( arrow_image, i );
namedWindow("Drawing arrow");
system("aplay a_12.wav&"); /*play sound*/
imshow("Drawing arrow", arrow_image);
cvWaitKey(1000*ts); /*this is the delay */
destroyWindow("Drawing arrow");
 }

void Arrow( Mat img, int i ) 
{  
 int lineType = 8;
 Point arrow_points[1][7];
if (i == 1) { //left  
  arrow_points[0][0] = Point( 90*mp, 60*mp );
  arrow_points[0][1] = Point( 90*mp, 40*mp );
  arrow_points[0][2] = Point( 50*mp, 40*mp );
  arrow_points[0][3] = Point( 50*mp, 30*mp );
  arrow_points[0][4] = Point( 10*mp, 50*mp );
  arrow_points[0][5] = Point( 50*mp, 70*mp );
  arrow_points[0][6] = Point( 50*mp, 60*mp );
};
if (i == 2) { //right 
  arrow_points[0][0] = Point( 20*mp, 60*mp );
  arrow_points[0][1] = Point( 20*mp, 40*mp );
  arrow_points[0][2] = Point( 60*mp, 40*mp );
  arrow_points[0][3] = Point( 60*mp, 30*mp );
  arrow_points[0][4] = Point( 100*mp, 50*mp );
  arrow_points[0][5] = Point( 60*mp, 70*mp );
  arrow_points[0][6] = Point( 60*mp, 60*mp );
};
if (i == 3) { //down
 arrow_points[0][0] = Point( 60*mp, 20*mp );
 arrow_points[0][1] = Point( 40*mp, 20*mp );
 arrow_points[0][2] = Point( 40*mp, 60*mp );
 arrow_points[0][3] = Point( 30*mp, 60*mp );
 arrow_points[0][4] = Point( 50*mp, 100*mp );
 arrow_points[0][5] = Point( 70*mp, 60*mp );
 arrow_points[0][6] = Point( 60*mp, 60*mp );
};
const Point* ppt[1] = { arrow_points[0] };
 int npt[] = { 7 };
 fillPoly( img,
    ppt,
    npt,
        1,
    Scalar( 250, 0, 0 ),
    lineType );
}
```

Comment: You may get better trackaction if you add C as a language. Though you use one C++ class the code for review is basically C no real C++ features used so you may as well ask for comments from C coders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice.  I am working on a similar project.  In order to make your code more modular and object oriented, you can write a `Message` class and a `SerialPort` class.  It makes it much easier to restructure your code when you want to change the behavior. e.g.

```
SerialPort sp("COM8"); // or "/dev/ttyUSB0" for linux
Message msg("alskadflaskjfd");
Message rx;

sp.write(msg);
sp.read(rx);
```

You might as well since your using some c++, modularity is always a good thing.